# Fetch Type vs Fetch Mode in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

Suppose I am using Eager+ select (fetching statergy) as below, collectins will be loaded lazily or eagerly ?

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.Eager, mappedBy = "stock")

        @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
        public Set<StockDailyRecord> getStockDailyRecords() {
            return this.stockDailyRecords;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Collection will be eagerly.

> We have two notions: What should be fetched and how should it be
>   fetched. There are two different and complementary tuning strategies,
>   global and per use case.

https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/AShortPrimerOnFetchingStrategies